# android resources string-array "invalid character"

Tags: android, arrays, string, resources

In `resource array-string` I've put:

```
<string-array name="Gefühle_de">
<item>xxx</item>
</string-array>
```

But I received the error as **Invalid character** on `Gefühle` (this is a **deutsch** language).
How to resolve the problem?

Comment: is this in arrays.xml under /res/values?

Comment: @Raghunandan this can go in strings.xml under /res/values. No need for arrays.xml.

Comment: @TronicZomB i know i was just clarifying coz the above worked for me. I don't see a problem

Comment: @Raghunandan the only two things I see are the capital letter, Android complains about that sometimes when they are in xml files, and the umlaut could be a problem, but I'm not entirely sure on that one.

Comment: @TronicZomB it worked for me even if i had this "Gefühle_de".

Comment: @Raghunandan interesting. I just suggested OP clean his project in the comments to my answer. That maybe, possibly will fix it... its worth a shot at least.

Comment: with uppercase I don't have problem

Comment: @TronicZomB do you have try with Gefühle_de and works?

Comment: @shuttle1978 I would love to test this for you but currently my eclipse is misbehaving and I am working on uninstalling and reinstalling. If you don't figure this out in.. ohh.. about an hour I will try it and see what I can find.

Answer (score 3):

I think the issue is the uppercase G, for the string-array name.

Must be :

```
<string-array name="gefühle_de">
<item>xxx</item>
</string-array>
```

Edit : Do you really need the 'ü' char for the name, 'u' is not enough?

The best practice is to avoid uppercase, and accent chars for the tag names.

Comment: i am very agree with what @Shemsu-Hor said, remeber be always use a standard naming rule, english is okay enough

Comment: with string gefühle_de I receive the same error, the ü is necessary because is a deutsch word, I don't know if the same thing without it

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the base Androind can't not recognize the Umlaut on the "u" within the `name` attribute. Try to set as `name="gefuhle_de"`.

**EDIT:** When I put the original value with the umlaut into my strings.xml, this is what my R.java came out as:

```
public final class R {
public static final class array {
    public static final int GefÃ¼hle_de=0x7f070001;
    public static final int spin=0x7f070000;
}
```

It is producing an error on the fractional character (5th one from the left). This seems to indicate that the umlaut is causing the problem. Try to remove the umlaut, lower case the "G" (not necessary in my case actually), and then clean your project.

Comment: Yes I've tried but doesn't work, I've followed your advice, I've remove the 'ü' character

Comment: if removing the umlaut and cleaning don't work that this is quite an interesting problem you have...